# Spree commerce 2-4-stable, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, inventory-management

I am using spree 2-4-stable version and would like to update stocks via a xml file. Right now i have a single stock location and none of the stock items on product creation is backorderable. Also the count on hand is 0 for all.

What i need to know here is the flow of how the stock management works so that i can upload stocks from a xml file which supplies me just the number of available stocks in my warehouse.

Comment: You can directly import the products in the backend , but the quantity will have to be set by you manually

Comment: For example , if there are 50 quantity availaible and there's an order for 20 . The availaible quantity would update to 30 but you will have to mention the quantity as 50 manually

Comment: Okay! I get this, but i am more concerned at the code level as to how the stock items are updated via stock movements for a single stock location. Also i found a column of stock_items_count in variants which shows a value of 1 on product creation.

Comment: Yes , for maintaining stock items there's a controller . You can override each and every controller of spree provided that u make it in the exact place where it's there in the github repo . Let's say , the stock_items controller is located inside app/controllers/admin/stock_items.rb ...then you can make a same file in your local project and override the methods of that controller according to your usage .

Comment: In your case , this is the file ...also make sure you check the code in the correct branch ..yours being 2.4 - https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-4-stable/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/stock_items_controller.rb and https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-4-stable/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/stock_movements_controller.rb